# Cannot find Zcash params

Tags: node

recently I rebooted my laptop and I get the below message when I try to run the node.

Any idea what I should do? I installed the latest PPA binaries.

Thanks,

ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ tezos-node
Failed to initialize Zcash parameters: cannot find Zcash params in any of:

- /home/ubuntu/.local/share/zcash-params
- /usr/share/ubuntu/zcash-params
- /usr/local/share/zcash-params
- /usr/share/zcash-params
- /var/lib/snapd/desktop/zcash-params
- /home/ubuntu/.zcash-params
  You may download them using https://raw.githubusercontent.com/zcash/zcash/master/zcutil/fetch-params.sh

Answer (score 1):

The release notes for 7.5+ contain instructions for getting rust built and the Zcash stuff. Make sure to check them out on the Gitlab.

Here’s the rust info http://tezos.gitlab.io/introduction/howtoget.html#setup-rust

Answer (score 0):

OK - got it:
wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/zcash/zcash/master/zcutil/fetch-params.sh
chmod +x fetch-params.sh
./fetch-params.sh

Any ideas what these params are for?

PS: happy this works because building from scratch didn't work anymore (rust missing)

Comment: "Any ideas what these params are for?" -> these are used by [Sapling](https://tezos.gitlab.io/008/sapling.html)